I need help with audio drivers for a twenty ninteen iMac
I tried using Alsa and fulsefire along with all these others things people were telling me to use and it still doesn't work. It's an SND HDA intel Audio card.

As you've not yet told us what Ubuntu product & release of that product you're seeking help on, we currently can't offer much. Specifics of your hardware also help (esp. chipset), plus details of what docs you've tried to follow, and what didn't work etc.

24.10 LTS Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [8086:a348] (rev 10)

This is a question & answer site; comments are from readers and will get removed once addressed; if you have additional details or corrections, please add them to your question (comments get removed once addressed in question; answers will be to details in the question itself, not comments).  Your details make little sense, Ubuntu 24.10 is not a LTS, so are you using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS or Ubuntu 24.10 ?  and which Ubuntu 24.04/24.10 system (ie. Desktop or Server).
